# Regex to find the first capital letter in a string

Tags: regex

I have looked all over for an answer to this, but no one has had quite the same question as I do.

The problem I am trying to solve is to find the first capital letter in a string and no other capital letters. I have been able to narrow my search to each instance of a capital letter, but no amount of quantifiers I could find can make it only the first one.

For example, in this String abcDefgH. I only want to match the D and not the H.

Comment: This seems to be just a `[A-Z]`, what is your exact problem?

Comment: If you do not provide details, the question will have to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple
`([A-Z])`I maybe missunderstood your question, but this will select only the first Capitalized letter in string.

Comment: The problem is most likely with the regex usage, as `[A-Z]` is just a basic regex construct, and there are a lot of methods that perform global search by default. So, we need to get more problem details from OP before we can actually help.

Comment: ([A-Z]) matches all the uppercase letters i just want to match the first uppercase letter and no other ones.

Comment: ([A-Z]) matches only the first occurance, if you **DO NOT** use *global* tag